# Why does Cx_Freeze load so many libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I've made a pygame project and I wanted to turn it into an Executable. For that reason, I used Cx-Freeze.
However, I've noticed that the `build/exe.win32-3.8/lib` folder has many libraries that I don't use in this specific project.

Does anybody know how to choose which libraries will be loaded, or any other solution?